# How to use $text search inside $lookup pipeline

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregate

I have the next collection for exaple:

```
// vehicles collection

[
  {
    "_id": 321,
    manufactor: SOME-OBJECT-ID
  },
  {
    "_id": 123,
    manufactor: ANOTHER-OBJECT-ID
  },
]
```

And I have a collection named tables:

```
// tables collection
[
  {
    "_id": SOME-OBJECT-ID,
    title: "Skoda"
  },
  {
    "_id": ANOTHER-OBJECT-ID,
    title: "Mercedes"
  },
]
```

As you can see, the vehicles collection's documents are pulling data from the 
tables's collection ducments - the first document in the vehicles collection has a manufactor 
id which is getting pulled from the tables collection and named Skoda.

That is great.

When I am querying the DB using aggregate I can able to easily pull the remote data from the remote collections
respectively - without any problem.
I can also easily make rules and limitations like $project, $sort, $skip, $limit and others.

But I want to display to the user only those vehicles that are manufcatord by Mercedes.
Since Mercedes is not mentioned in the vehicles collection, but only its ID, the $text $search would not
return with the right results.

This is the aggregate pipeline that I provide:

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      $text: {
        $search: "Mercedes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tables",
      let: {
        manufactor: "$manufactor"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id", "$$manufactor"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            title: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "manufactor"
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$manufactor"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tables",
      let: {
        model: "$model"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id", "$$model"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            title: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "model"
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$model"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {
        joined_by: "$_joined_by"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id", "$$joined_by"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            personal_info: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "joined_by"
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$joined_by"
  }
]
```

As you can see I am using the $text and $search $match at the first stage in the pipleline - otherwise 
MongoDB will throw an error.

But this $text $search object searhed only in the origin collection - the vehicles collection.

Is there a way to tell MongoDB to search in the remote collection with the $text and $search method
and then put in the aggregate only results that are matching both?

**UPDATE**

When I am doing this instead:

```
     {
      $lookup: {
        from: "tables",
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $text: {
                $search: "Mercedes"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              title: 1
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "manufactor"
      },
    },
```

This is what I receive:

```
 MongoError: pipeline requires text score metadata, but there is no text score available
```

Comment: You cannot use `$text` index in the `$lookup` pipeline. Even if you to do that then start the aggregation from the child collection and join the parent with the `$lookup`. I am not sure about this but may be some mongo developer can better explain this. But as far as I know you cannot use inside the `$lookup` pipeline.

Comment: Got it. Should I create two collections - vehicles and vehiclesSearch? In vehicles I will store ID(s) and in the vehiclesSearch I will store absolute data?

Comment: No comments on model structure. It depends on your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using one of the affected versions in this [thread](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38716), you need to update your mongodb server.
As you can see the issue was fixed in version 4.1.8